# What is the meaning of "faire une touche"?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

The following text is from an essay by philosopher Jean-Luc Nancy:

"[...] une touche au sens d'une touche de couleur, au sens de la touche d'un pianiste, et pourquoi pas au sens ou on disait dans le vieil argot, faire une touche"

What is the meaning of *faire une touche* in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> faire une touche

signifie

> se faire remarquer par une personne que l'on veut séduire

C'est une expression que je qualifierais d'assez vieillotte.

Comment: Et plus ancien mais moins vieillot, c'est utilisé par les pêcheurs pour dire que le poisson à mordu.